# Multiple calls to the same endpoint with different results in webmock?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, webmock

I have some code that looks like this:

```
while response.droplet.status != env["user_droplet_desired_state"] do
   sleep 2
   response = ocean.droplet.show env["droplet_id"]
   say ".", nil, false
end
```

The idea being you can set the app to wait until the server is in a certain state (eg. restart it, then watch it until it's active again)

However, I'm using webmock in the tests, and I can't figure out a way to give a different response the second time.

For example, code like this:

```
  stub_request(:get, "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/6918990?per_page=200").
     with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Authorization'=>'Bearer foo', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.9.2'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => fixture('show_droplet_inactive'), :headers => {})

  stub_request(:get, "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/6918990?per_page=200").
     with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Authorization'=>'Bearer foo', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Faraday v0.9.2'}).
     to_return(:status => 200, :body => fixture('show_droplet'), :headers => {})
```

With the idea being "First time mark as in-active so the loop goes through one-time, then mark as active afterwards"

[The documentation says that stubs are just done as "Last one found will work":](https://github.com/webmock/webmock#precedence-of-stubs)

> Always the last declared stub matching the request will be applied
>   i.e:
>
> stub_request(:get, "www.example.com").to_return(:body => "abc")
>
> stub_request(:get, "www.example.com").to_return(:body => "def")
>
> Net::HTTP.get('www.example.com', '/')   # ====> "def"

Is it possible to model multiple calls to the same endpoint with different results in webmock?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you pass multiple arguments to `#to_return`, it will respond each time with the next response, and then just keep returning the last one over and over.  For example:

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
require 'uri'

describe "something" do
   it "happens" do
      stub_request(:get, 'example.com/blah').
        to_return({status: 200, body: 'ohai'}, {status: 200, body: 'there'})

      puts Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://example.com/blah'))
      puts Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://example.com/blah'))
      puts Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://example.com/blah'))
      puts Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://example.com/blah'))
   end
end
```

When run as `rspec <file>`, this will print:

```
ohai
there
there
there
```